# About install ubuntu for devices on Chinese android tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, devices

Is it possible to install ubuntu for devices (ubuntu touch) on a Chinese android tablet ?
I saw a guide on ubuntu website about how to install ubuntu for devices on android tablets/phones.
If its possible what is the worst case scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch also known as Ubuntu for devices or Ubuntu Phone, it’s crucial to know that the process will completely erase your device, removing not only Android but also your apps, photos and all other data. You absolutely must back up everything you want to keep first.

Here are instructions for installing Ubuntu on devices (phone and tablet) [installing-ubuntu-for-devices](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

There’s a bigger list of devices  [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)

If you want to reinstall android [reinstalling-android](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/reinstalling-android/)

> NOTE: Some of the links in this post are no longer functioning as a result of Ubuntu Touch being discontinued; the links have been left in place for historical reasons.

Comment: Is it sure that it will boot ?